# opencv возвращает None

Tags: python, python-2.x, видео, opencv, streaming

Привет. Мне нужно захватить видео с камеры. Но `cv2` на python2.7 возвращает None. Подскажите.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


import cv2

print cv2.__version__

# cap = cv2.VideoCapture(-1)
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)


while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
```

На текущий момент я пытаюсь найти функцию, которая бы вернула список камер, посмотреть видит ли openCV мою камеру или нет. Но пока попытки тщетны. Захватывать видео не обязательно с помощью openCV, поэтому любые другие либы приветствуются.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. убедитесь что камера видна как устройство V4L
2. подключите numpy:

   import numpy as np

Answer (score 0):

Наберите `ls /dev` там будут названия подключённых девайсов вас интересует `video0`, `video1` и т.д.